# How to Accept Hoor al Ayn?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I am a devout Muslimah who prays five times a day but the fact my husband will have Hoor al ayn makes me nervous and uncomfortable. It is affecting my relationship with Allah and I don't feel that much desire for Jannah. How can I accept the fact my husband gets Hoor al Ayn without it making me nervous or have a grudge?

Comment: Prophet will get atleast 2 hur al ayn, Aisha wasn't offended, neither was Zainab, further question is   Personal advice, offtopic

Comment: See [Quran 7:43](https://quran.com/7/43)

Comment: Would you deny him his right that Allah has made lawful for him? For your husband to get Hoor al ayn is one thing, he can marry atleast three other girls or buy unlimited amount of slave girls to fulfil his sexual desires even in this world, today or tomorrow. He also has the right to divorce you and marry someone else. you cannot be a control freak and make something haram, which is halal for him. A devout Muslima is the one who accepts Islam without questioning the authority of God. you are suppose to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

### There will be no grudges or ill-feelings in Paradise

Allah informs us that the inhabitants of Paradise will be in a state of peace and tranquility, such that there will be no grudges, envy or hatred between any two of them.

> (وَنَزَعْنَا مَا فِي صُدُورِهِمْ مِنْ غِلٍّ إِخْوَانًا عَلَىٰ سُرُرٍ مُتَقَابِلِينَ)
>   [Surat Al-Hijr 47]
>
> ***And We will remove whatever is in their breasts of resentment***, [so they will be] brothers, on thrones facing each other.

So although this feeling of jealousy (which is totally natural and not something blameworthy) is present in this life, it will not be present in the next life for the people of Paradise.