# In my jannah can there be no hoors, while in my husband's jannah he will have hoors?

Tags: jannah

I have been struggling to accept that my husband would get multiple companions and that it would be selfish of me not to allow him to enjoy this reward. This is bounty of Allah.

Then this struck me, what if in MY jannah, there will be no Hoor al Ayn, just me and my husband while in my husband's Jannah he will have hoors?

Allah said whatever I desire, so maybe Allah can make a duplicate of my husband and in my Jannah I will be his one and only and his other self can enjoy the Hoor al Ayn in his Jannah?

That way we both get what we want!

Comment: Why did you ask this question 3 times?                https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41316/how-to-accept-hoor-al-ayn

Comment: This seems like an opinion based question. The general answer is that yes it would be granted in some way since Allah says: [**41:31**](https://quran.com/41/31) ***And you will have therein whatever your souls desire, and you will have therein whatever you request [or wish]***

Comment: I think you can ask for 70 million slaves or more for yourself as well, to balance out the pleasure. As you are entitled to demand and get whatever your soul desire.  you can make you both even. However that purely depends on your will. Most people will go for an orgy first hand if they are allowed to have it.

Comment: Why should you have your own Jannah: be aware that once you are there you will find everything that satisfies your needs you won't be thinking the way you are now as there's no reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Hereafter is entirely different than this earthly life. One of those ways in which it is different is that all negative emotions will be removed. So you are worrying about a paradise based on the emotions and jealousies of this life, while Al-Akhira is an entirely different world/timelessness. Not only will you get what your heart desires, but the desires of your heart, in the Presence and acceptance of Allah, will not be at all like they are in this life, neither did you nor for your husband. He too shouldn't place all his stock in earthly imaginings about hoor al-'ein. Because the nature of desire in the Hereafter is not like that of this world.

There will be no childbirth, hence no procreation in the usual sense. There will be no betrayal or sense of unfairness whatsoever. All people who enter paradise will be cleansed of any hatred or negative emotions in their hearts.

7:43

> And We will have removed whatever is within their breasts of
>   resentment, [while] flowing beneath them are rivers. And they will
>   say, "Praise to Allah, who has guided us to this; and we would never
>   have been guided if Allah had not guided us. Certainly the messengers
>   of our Lord had come with the truth." And they will be called, "This
>   is Paradise, which you have been made to inherit for what you used to
>   do."

The Arabic word "ghil" is similar to frustration and resentment, and this sort of emotion is exactly what you are describing above. Part of what makes Paradise so unimaginably wonderful is this removal of such emotions from the heart. For the believer, however, closeness to Allah, good far beyond imagination, is far more fulfilling than anything one can quibble about in this life. All worries and anxieties fall away. Trust this, and here is one instance where the height of optimism should be employed: Janna is way beyond any earthly pleasures, and the more you look forward to Allah's acceptance, in reverence, the less you will worry about that. No one on this life really knows what will be in Paradise except what Allah has revealed, and much of that is really similitude or allegory to give us a sense of the magnitude of it, but these indications are not to be taken so literally. Trust that Allah who is all capable is surely more than capable of rewarding the believers with complete fairness and fulfillment. Don't quibble over who gets what. Perhaps in the next life gender will be irrelevant, or at least not having the hierarchy of superior/ inferior we have in this life. The joy of interaction with believers will be indescribable. There is no good like that given by Allah!

If you must worry about something, it should be about how you are behaving in this earthly life, which is a test. It is we who fall short, never, never the promises of the All-Merciful.

Answer (score 0):

Bear sabr sister. You will find out once you reach Jannah In shaa Allah. Allah's reward is mighty. He says he has prepared for his righteous slaves in Jannah that which no eye has seen, no ear has heard and no heart has conceived.

> Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Allah has said: I have prepared for My righteous servants what no eye has seen, what no ear has heard, and what no heart has conceived. So recite if you wish: No person knows what is kept hidden for them of delights of the eye as a reward for what they used to do (32:17). And in Paradise there is a tree under whose shade a rider can travel for one hundred years without stopping. Recite if you wish: In shade extended (56:30). And the space in Paradise occupied by a whip is better than the whole world and everything in it. Recite if you wish: Whoever is removed from the Hellfire and entered into Paradise is indeed successful, for the life of this world is only the enjoyment of deception.” (3:185)

So you will not be dissapointed. I hope you reflect on this and make dua to Allah as he is the turner of hearts.